# not to + verb VS don't + verb

Tags: negation

Recently a student of mine made the following mistake :
"I want my family don't need anything".
I corrected it to "I want my family not to need anything". But when asked why I used "not to" instead of "don't", I couldn't explain why.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it help simplify things if you take out the negation and compare “I want my family to need” vs. “I want my family need”/“I want my family do need”?

Comment: I would have corrected it to "I want my family to not need anything" in this case the split infinitive makes the sentence meaning clearer.

Comment: Hm... would "I want that my family don't need anything" be considered correct?

Comment: Hello, thank you all for your help! It was explained to be by a colleague:

Comment: With the verbs want and expect you have to put an infinitive not an auxiliary.

Answer (score 3):

The verb *want* takes an infinitive after it, not an auxiliary verb.

For example, you can't say

> *I want can fly.

You have to say

> I want to be able to fly.

Answer (score -1):

*To want* takes an object, when that object is a thing.

> I want a pony.
>
> I want more money.
>
> I want world peace.

*To want* takes *to* + infinitive, when an action is wanted, for the subject to do.

> I want to sleep.
>
> I don’t want to work.
>
> I want to go to the beach.
>
> I want to be able to fly.

*To want* takes an object + *to* + infinitive, when an action is wanted, for another person to do.

> I want the baby to sleep.
>
> I want him to work.
>
> I want you to go to the beach with me.
>
> I want my brother to be able to swim.
>
> I don’t want them to need me.
>
> I want my family not to need anything.

*To want* can also take a noun clause describing an action, starting with *that*. But these formulations are not preferred. The ones above sound better.

> I want that the baby sleeps.
>
> I want that I can fly.
>
> I want that my brother can swim.
>
> I don’t want that they need me.
>
> I want that my family doesn’t need anything.

You can add stress by changing the order of the sentence, starting with the noun clause, and referring to it with a second *that*.

> That my family doesn’t need anything, that’s what I want!

That works with regular objects as well.

> A pony, that’s what I want!